# In Java, how can I treat empty class constructors differently when evaluating for emptyConstructor condition?

Tags: java, class, constructor, boolean

I am trying to make it so that the console will print "empty constructor called" for every empty class constructor with default parameters and "constructor with parameters called" for every class constructor containing specified parameters. As you can see in the Main class, myAccount and yourAccount are empty constructors, and only johnnysAccount has parameters specified.

Here is my Main class.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount myAccount = new BankAccount();
        BankAccount yourAccount = new BankAccount();
        BankAccount johnnysAccount = new BankAccount("Mr. Appleseed", 533333202258L,
                8121283434L, "jappleseed@applecorp.co", 470.45);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the BankAccount class, the console should print a different message for empty constructors with default parameters than for constructors with parameters specified.

Here is my BankAccount class.

```
public class BankAccount {
    private String customer;
    private long number;
    private long telephone;
    private String email;
    private double balance;
    private boolean emptyConstructor;

    public BankAccount() {
        this("Nobody", 111111111111L, 18008888888L, "email@email.com", 0.00);
        emptyConstructor = true;
        System.out.println(emptyConstructor);
        if(emptyConstructor) {
            System.out.println("Empty constructor called.");
        }
    }

    public BankAccount (String customer, long number, long telephone, String email, double balance) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.number = number;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.email = email;
        this.balance = balance;
        emptyConstructor = false;
        System.out.println(emptyConstructor);
        if(!emptyConstructor) {
            System.out.println("Constructor with parameters called.");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my output.

```
false
Constructor with parameters called.
true
Empty constructor called.
false
Constructor with parameters called.
true
Empty constructor called.
false
Constructor with parameters called.
```

As expected, emptyConstructor evaluates to false and prints "constructor with parameters called" for johnnysAccount in the last two lines of output. However, it appears that for the two empty constructors myAccount and yourAccount, emptyConstructor evaluates to false and then true, printing both messages. I can only get the desired output if I comment out

```
this("Nobody", 111111111111L, 18008888888L, "email@email.com", 0.00);
```

However, I would rather keep the default parameters in place. Is there any other way I can make it so that emptyConstructor only evaluates to true and only prints the message "empty constructor called" for empty constructors with default parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be more readable... if you assign default value in no-arg constructor also

```
public BankAccount() {
    System.out.println("Empty constructor called.");
    this.customer = "Nobody";
    this.number = 111111111111L;
    this.telephone = 18008888888L;
    this.email = "email@email.com";
    this.balance = 0.00;
}

public BankAccount (String customer, long number, long telephone, String email, double balance) {
    System.out.println("Constructor with parameters called.");
    this.customer = customer;
    this.number = number;
    this.telephone = telephone;
    this.email = email;
    this.balance = balance;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There could be a private constructor such as:

```
private BankAccount (String customer, long number, long telephone, String email, double balance, boolean calledFromNoArgConstructor) {
    this.customer = customer;
    this.number = number;
    this.telephone = telephone;
    this.email = email;
    this.balance = balance;
    if(calledFromNoArgConstructor) {
        System.out.println("Empty constructor called.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Constructor with parameters called.");
    }
}
```

then the public constructors can delegate to the private constructor:

```
public BankAccount() {
    this("Nobody", 111111111111L, 18008888888L, "email@email.com", 0.00, true);
}

public BankAccount (String customer, long number, long telephone, String email, double balance) {
    this(customer, number, telephone, email, balance, false);
}
```